# HTTP being changed to HTTPS in src of iframe in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, https, laravel-8

I am trying to make iframe in my Laravel project.

URL for iframe is **http**://buckymaler.com/apollo/ that is stored in database

In iframe I am getting url for source like this:

```
<iframe src="{{$portfolio->link}}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But when I open this page on browser url is being changed to **https**://buckymaler.com/apollo/

In AppServiceProvider.php has no anything:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I am working in VPS server.

If you have solution, Please, help me!

Comment: Is it changing in the HTML or the DOM?

Comment: When I click inspect to see Html codes there is https is written

Comment: How about when you view the raw HTML source?

Comment: there, also https is written

Comment: if you want you can see here: https://www.abdurakhmon.com/Apollo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have knew that if my domen is working with https, it makes every links and src https.
My domen connected to VPS server by cloudflare.com. To solve this problem, in dashboard of cloudflare, "Always Use HTTPS" should be turned off!